# Study design: assigning individuals matched treatments+controls to the same or different batches?

Tags: experiment-design

I'm considering an experimental set up whereby I have 20 individuals (1-20), and each individual has a control and a treatment sample (C,T), resulting in 40 collected samples in total. Now we would like to measure gene expression from these samples (40 experiments, 1 per sample) in batches. Say we decide to run in 4 batches (A,B,C,D). I expect to see strong effects both the between individuals and between the batches.

Then, from a statistical perspective, is it better to ensure that each given individual is always assigned to the same batch (e.g. individual 1 treatment and control both in batch A), and simply use the matched paired information to control for the batch effects, or to randomly assign the treatments and controls per individual to different batches?

The first scenario (assign pair to same batch) looks like this:

`batch ind treat
      A   1     T
      A   1     C
      A   2     T
      A   2     C
      A   3     T
      A   3     C
      A   4     T
      A   4     C
      A   5     T
      A   5     C
      B   6     T
      B   6     C
      B   7     T
      B   7     C
      B   8     T
      B   8     C
      B   9     T
      B   9     C
      B  10     T
      B  10     C
      C  11     T
      C  11     C
      C  12     T
      C  12     C
      C  13     T
      C  13     C
      C  14     T
      C  14     C
      C  15     T
      C  15     C
      D  16     T
      D  16     C
      D  17     T
      D  17     C
      D  18     T
      D  18     C
      D  19     T
      D  19     C
      D  20     T
      D  20     C`

Here one cannot block both individual and batch effects so I would have to fit only the individual effects and ignore the batch information.

In the second scenario, you would have the controls and treatments assigned to different batches (balanced so that the same number of treatments and controls are in each batch). So I would have to estimate the batch effects in order to correctly determine the measured individual response to the treatment.

So on one hand including an individual within a batch helps us to see the differences between control and treatment without worrying about batch effects, and on the other hand, separating individuals across batches means we can get around confounding and obtain more accurate estimates of the batch effects themselves.

Which of these two scenarios is most robust statistically (for obtaining information about the treatment size and the individual responses to the treatment)?

Answer (score 0):

I like your first idea better. Your chief interest is within-subjects comparisons, and it will be easier to do this if batch is held constant for each subject. At the same time, you should randomly assign subjects to batches (to ensure batch is unrelated to anything of interest), and it may be helpful to control for batch in a regression model (even though batch isn't of substantive interest, controlling for it could let you estimate the effects of interest more precisely).